# I'm taking statics, and I'm stuck on this truss problem, how do do I solve this?

Tags: statics

[image]

I'm an engineering student, our professor assigned us this truss problem I found $A_y$ and $L_y$ by using the moment about l, and found ab, now what? It seems like I have too many unknowns to solve for after that...

Comment: Think about what else you can find by considering the equilibrium of the other joints, one at a time. For example, what can you say about F?

Comment: Well I 've already identified the zero force members...

Comment: guess I should have said that earlier...

Comment: I still haven't found a way to answer for the rest of the problem, though, could someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you've already identified the zero-force members, so I'll skip part (a) of the question. The structure then becomes (deleting all the zero-force members except for DE which is needed for structural stability):

[image]

In this case, I prefer to work from the cantilever and then move in.

Since we know DE is zero-force, we therefore know $EG = 20\text{ kN (compression)}$.

Since the only other member with a vertical component on $G$ is $DG$, we can obtain that $$\begin{align}
DG &= 20\times\dfrac{\sqrt{7^2+DG_v^2}}{DG_v} \\
\text{where }DG_v &= \dfrac{5}{3\times7}\times2\times7 = 3.33\text{ m} \\
\therefore DG &= 46.5\text{ kN (tension)} \\
\therefore GH &= 46.5\times\dfrac{7}{\sqrt{7^2+3.33^2}} = 42.0\text{ kN (compression)}
\end{align}$$

Looking at $D$, we have the applied load, $CD$ (with horizontal and diagonal components), $DE$ (which we know is zero-force), $DG$ and $DH$. $CD$ is the only one which can absorb $DG$'s horizontal component (which is equal to the result found for $GH$, so we can find that

$$\begin{align}
CD &= 42.0\times\dfrac{\sqrt{7^2+CD_v^2}}{7} \\
\text{where }CD_v &= 5 - 3.33 = 1.67\text{ m} \\
\therefore CD &= 43.2\text{ kN (tension)} \\
\therefore DH &= 43.2\times\dfrac{1.67}{\sqrt{7^2+1.67^2}} - 46.5\times\dfrac{3.33}{\sqrt{7^2+3.33^2}} + 40 = 50\text{ kN (compression)}
\end{align}$$

Likewise, looking at $H$, only $CH$ can absorb $DH$'s vertical load, so by repeating the calculations above, we get that:

$$\begin{align}
CH &= 86.0\text{ kN (tension)} \\
HI &= 112.0\text{ kN (compression)}
\end{align}$$

And then looking at $C$, only $BC$ can absorb $CD$'s and $CH$'s horizontal components, so we then calculate that:

$$\begin{align}
BC &= 169.3\text{ kN (tension)} \\
CI &= 195.3\text{ kN (compression)}
\end{align}$$

Obviously $BI = HI = 112.0\text{ kN (compression)}$ and $IL = CI = 195.3\text{ kN (compression)}$.

Then looking at $A$, we use your previously calculated reactions to obtain

$$\begin{align}
AB &= 84.8\text{ kN (tension)} \\
AL &= 10.1\text{ kN (compression)}
\end{align}$$

And likewise with $L$ (or from $B$), we obtain the last remaining $BL = 23.8\text{ kN (tension)}$.

And we're done.

[image]